# Manipulation Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array something like this..

```
 var array = [2,a,b,3]
```

i want to arrange that so it can show console array like this

```
//console.log
[1,a,b,1]
[1,a,b,2]
[1,a,b,3]
[2,a,b,1]
[2,a,b,2]
[2,a,b,3]
```

update

what if i want loop every number in array, and what if that array not static but dynamic

```
var array = [2,'a','b',3]
var array = [2,'a',4,'c','b',3]
var array = [2,'a']
```

and i want put that console result in array

if any body want know why i do this this cos i have nasted array i save all Object.prototypename inside an array so i can call it leater,

this axample

```
var data = [{a:0,b:[{c:0},{c:0}]},{a:0,b:[{c:0},{c:0}]}]
```

i have function so it will return

```
[2,a,b,2,c]
```

then i can call it

```
data [2][a][b][2][c]
```

my function can return anything acording to selected data so i want to make this, but stuck in here

Comment: Ok, you have one array then you want 5 more arrays?

Comment: What about `[1, c, 4, d, e, 2]`??

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It doesn't seem like the output you want has anything to do with the original array.

Comment: And what about negative numbers such as: `[-5, c]`??

Comment: that array is hold the location of element in my Object array, that mean in my object Array have 2 object Object and have element a and b that b is array that contains 3 object

Comment: Don't ask if something "is possible". Almost by definition it is, since we are working with computers which can be programmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function clone(arr, i, values) {
    var newArr = arr.slice();
    values.forEach(v => newArr[v.index] = Math.floor(i / v.breaker) % v.max + 1);
    return newArr;
}

function result(arr) {
    var n = 1,
        values = arr.reduceRight((acc, e, i) => {
            if(typeof e === "number") {
                acc.push({
                    index: i,
                    max: e,
                    breaker: n
                });
                n *= e;
            }
            return acc;
        }, []);
    
    var res = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res.push(clone(arr, i, values));
    }
    return res;
}

console.log( result([2,'a','b',3,4]) );
```

---

**Explaining with an example:**

Let `arr` be `[2, a, 3]`.

Then `values` will be:

```
[
    {
        index: 0,
        max: 2,
        breaker: 3
    },
    {
        index: 2,
        max: 3,
        breaker: 1
    }
]
```

And `n`, the number of permutations is: `2 * 3 === 6`.

**Usage of the `breaker` property:**

When the `clone` function clones the array, it will update the clone's numbers according to the index of the current permutation `i`.

The `breaker`, makes it possible to not increment the early (first-to-encounter) numbers more frequently. To increment a number we need to wait `N` times (permutaions) where `N` is the number of permutations of the numbers on the left of this number. In the above example: we update `2`'s place every `3` permutations (everytime `3`'s place has completed a cycle).

If the array is: `[2, 3, 7]` then:

- To increment `7`'s number we won't have to wait. It will just cycle, uninterruptely, untill all permutations are done. Thus **`breaker === 1`**.
- To increment `3`' number we'll have to wait for `7`'s to complete a cycle. `7`'s will take `7` permutations to complete one, thus **`breaker === 7`**.
- To increment `2`'s number, we'll have to wait for `3`'s to complete a cycle which also have to wait for `7`'s to complete one. So we have to wait `3` times `7`, thus **`breaker === 3 * 7 === 21`**.

The `breaker` of a number is just the number of permutations the number on its left takes to complete a cycle.

**Explaining the `clone` function:**

The `clone` function takes:

- `arr`: the array to be cloned and modified according to the current permutation's index.
- `i`: the current permutation's index.
- `values`: the array of the data objects that contain informations about all the numbers in the array `arr` (the index of the number, the maximum value it can take, its `breaker` value).

The function starts by creating a clone for the array (`var newArr = arr.slice();`). Then loop over all the data objects in the `values` array, calculating the value of the number:

```
theValueOfTheNumber = (indexOfCurrentPermutation / breaker) % maximumValuePossible + 1;
```

We start by dividing the index of the current permutation by the breaker to ensure that the value won't be incremented untill the number on its left completed a cycle (If it takes `3` permutations to be incremented, then `0 / 3`, `1 / 3`, `2 / 3` will all be equal to `0` when applying `Math.floor`). Then we clamp the value so it won't exceed the maximum value allowed for it (the initial value) by using the **Modulo operator `%`** and the `+1` so values will be in the range `[1 -> maximumValuePossible]`.

**Explanation of `result` function:**

This function is simple, it just gather needed information such as the number of all permutations `n` and the `values` array.

It uses `reduceRight` to loop over the array from right to left, thus when encountering a number, we just assign the accumulated `n` (which will be the number of permutations on its left) as its `breaker` value.

After, we gather the informations, we just create a loop that loops the exact number of permutations, calling `clone` and pushing it returned value into the result array.

Comment: mate, dude, sir mr, cmoon really-really, aghhh.... you save me thanks, i really sad, thank you, good explaination, thanks all of you thanks stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

if your array fixed:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  for(j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    console.log("[" + i + ",a,b," + j +"]");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my array not fix, it maybe become [1, c, 4, d, e, 2] or any things,

Comment: can you explain more detail your question?

Comment: @Frog Update your question to include that input and show what the output would look like.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to iterate through the array:

```js
var array = [2, 'a', 'b', 3];
for(i = 1; i <= array[0]; i++) {
  for(j = 1; j <= array[3]; j++) {
    console.log("[" + i + array[1] + array[2] + j +"]");
  }
}
```

Comment: nice, but how about dynamic array, cos that is Object.propertyName, so it will not negative always real number, and strings, how if that array is dynamic?

Comment: i try using isNaN, to define if its is number, if number loop that, i try but faill, if that array change dynamicly

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var len = array.length;

for(i = 1; i <= array[0]; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j <= array[len-1]; j++) {
        console.log([i].concat( array.slice(1, len-1), [j]))
    }
}

[ 1, 'a', 'b', 1 ]
[ 1, 'a', 'b', 2 ]
[ 1, 'a', 'b', 3 ]
[ 2, 'a', 'b', 1 ]
[ 2, 'a', 'b', 2 ]
[ 2, 'a', 'b', 3 ]
```

Comment: thanks, but if i change the array to diferent value like [1, 'c', 4, 'd', 'e', 2], the sistem faill, can it running dynamicly? to any array input

Comment: What output do you want with the customized array given, do you want to loop over 4 as well? When I run the array with the code, it doesn't fail, it gives two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** My brain is about done for tonight but as I blankly stare at your question trying to figure out what you are trying to do and why you are trying to do it I started to think of a potential approach that is better than my current answer.

If the letter values are static, what you really care about is building a matrix based on the numbers. If you have [2,3] you want a two by three matrix with static letters in between. If you have a [3,3] you want a matrix of 9 rows of 2 items. [2,3,2] would be 12 rows of 3 items.

So if that's a correct assumption `[2,"a","b",3,"c",2]` would end up looking something like:

```
[1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,2,1]
[1,2,2]
[1,3,1]
[1,3,2]
[2,1,1]
[2,1,2]
[2,2,1]
[2,2,2]
[2,3,1]
[2,3,2]
```

Then adding the static content back in:

```
[1,"a","b",1,"c",1]
[1,"a","b",1,"c",2]
[1,"a","b",2,"c",1]
[1,"a","b",2,"c",2]
[1,"a","b",3,"c",1]
[1,"a","b",3,"c",2]
[2,"a","b",1,"c",1]
[2,"a","b",1,"c",2]
[2,"a","b",2,"c",1]
[2,"a","b",2,"c",2]
[2,"a","b",3,"c",1]
[2,"a","b",3,"c",2]
```

Is that remotely what you're looking for? Are the letters irrelevant other than that they need to show up in the final output?

Here's where I'm leaving off for tonight:

```
const data = [2, "a", "b", 3];

// Find the numbers
const numericData = data.filter(item => typeof item === 'number');
console.log(numericData); // [2,3]

// Build the matrix
const matrix = Array(2).fill()
                       .map(()=>Array(3).fill(0));
console.table(matrix);

// Populate the matrix

// Add static content back in
```

Original answer:

There's got to be a better way but here's one way.

```js
const data = [2, "a", "b", 3];

let output = [];

for (let x = 1; x <= data[0]; x++) {
  for (let y = 1; y <= data[3]; y++) {
    output.push([x, "a", "b", y]);
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

**Yields:**

```
[
[1,"a","b",1],
[1,"a","b",2],
[1,"a","b",3],
[2,"a","b",1],
[2,"a","b",2],
[2,"a","b",3]
]
```

Comment: nice one hold it on array, how about dynamic data?, so if i change data to [1, c, 4, d, e, 2]  it can still give me the result

Comment: Update your question to show what the output should look like in that scenario. I have a solution partially completed for dynamic but it is complicated as hell. I'm trying to use reduce to do what I think will work.

Comment: See my updated answer/now question with assumptions.

Comment: so i can make forEach function to show data[2][a][b][3][2] to call data inside my nasted array, i try make some thing dynamicly so user can choose the data